# How to update python 2.6 to python 2.7 in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux

I installed ubuntu 10.04 and it comes with python2.6. How can I upgrade it to 2.7?

Comment: python27 came preinstalled for me, maybe it's already installed? Try `ls /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: no, it wasn't installed in mine. Any other suggestion please..

Comment: If you are updating from Python 2.6, why not just go to Python 3?

Comment: @CoffeeRain Python 3 is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 7):

You can also install python2.7 package. Then you can define python version with shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`) or even use `#update-alternatives --config python` to make it default interpreter. But it can break a lot of system apps...

update: sometimes, there's no alternative to python, so you'll need to create those by hand. Something like `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7 10`

update2: nevertheless if you just need 2.7 for your project, I'd suggest using virtualenv: `virtualenv -ppython2.7 myproject`

Answer (score 2):

Download [python 2.7.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/) and follow the step. Just remember use `make install` dont do `make altinstall`, this will not make `python 2.7` as default python interpreter.

Edit: Don't replace or uninstall python 2.6 if it came with distro, this might lead to breaking packages.